# What are these google host entries that keep showing up automatically in my etc/hosts file?

Tags: macos, hosts

I went to edit my /etc/hosts file and found a bunch of entries for google urls that I never put there. When I try to delete it, it just comes back. I tried searching google for it but to no avail. Here is a small sampling of the entries:

```
216.239.32.20 www.google.ac # __CE_WATERMARK__
216.239.32.20 www.google.ad # __CE_WATERMARK__
216.239.32.20 www.google.ae # __CE_WATERMARK__
216.239.32.20 www.google.al # __CE_WATERMARK__
216.239.32.20 www.google.am # __CE_WATERMARK__
216.239.32.20 www.google.as # __CE_WATERMARK__
216.239.32.20 www.google.at # __CE_WATERMARK__
216.239.32.20 www.google.az # __CE_WATERMARK__
216.239.32.20 www.google.ba # __CE_WATERMARK__
216.239.32.20 www.google.be # __CE_WATERMARK__
216.239.32.20 www.google.bf # __CE_WATERMARK__
216.239.32.20 www.google.bg # __CE_WATERMARK__
216.239.32.20 www.google.bi # __CE_WATERMARK__
216.239.32.20 www.google.bj # __CE_WATERMARK__
216.239.32.20 www.google.bs # __CE_WATERMARK__
216.239.32.20 www.google.bt # __CE_WATERMARK__
216.239.32.20 www.google.by # __CE_WATERMARK__
216.239.32.20 www.google.ca # __CE_WATERMARK__
216.239.32.20 www.google.cat # __CE_WATERMARK__
216.239.32.20 www.google.cc # __CE_WATERMARK__
216.239.32.20 www.google.cd # __CE_WATERMARK__
216.239.32.20 www.google.cf # __CE_WATERMARK__
216.239.32.20 www.google.cg # __CE_WATERMARK__
216.239.32.20 www.google.ch # __CE_WATERMARK__
216.239.32.20 www.google.ci # __CE_WATERMARK__
216.239.32.20 www.google.cl # __CE_WATERMARK__
216.239.32.20 www.google.cm # __CE_WATERMARK__
216.239.32.20 www.google.cn # __CE_WATERMARK__
```

It goes on for about 242 lines. Any insight would be appreciated.

Comment: Are you using Kaspersky/[Covenant Eyes](http://www.covenanteyes.com/)? Then check [this](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/5258974?tstart=0)

Comment: Ah that makes sense now. I find it slightly unnerving that the software would do that. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

216.239.32.20 seems to be a legit Google Inc. IP-address - so nothing to worry about in the first instance: Please check [herdprotect.com](http://www.herdprotect.com/ip-address-216.239.32.20.aspx).

The behavior is probably related to Kaspersky Security. Check this [thread](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/5258974?tstart=0) at discussions.apple.com.

To prevent the flooding of your hosts file uninstall Kaspersky Security. Then clean it up by editing it with `sudo nano /etc/hosts`.